# Cannot load Oracle or MySQL driver in servlet through Eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, oracle, servlets

I have been wrestling with this problem for a few hours and getting frustrated.  Saw some posts here and on other sites with suggestions but none of them seem to be working for me.

I am writing some servlets.  I am using Eclipse with the JBoss 7.1 server.  That part is running well.  Servlets come up just fine.

I am trying to connect to an Oracle XE database.  Oracle is all configured and I have my tables set up.

I am trying to get my servlets to connect to the Oracle database, but it is failing at the first step in the process; it will not load the drivers.  The servlet named **LoginAction** attempts to make a database connection by calling a static method in another class, defined in a different file in the same package.  Here is the method charged with creating the database connection:

```
protected static Connection getDatabaseConnection()
{
    boolean driverloaded = true;

    //Load the driver.
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to load driver!");
        driverloaded = false;
    }

    if(driverloaded)
        System.out.println("loaded driver!");
    else
        return null;

    //Create and return a database Connection.
    try
    {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem making database connection!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Driver does load if I run the above class as an independent Java program.  I have later in the file a main function which I plan to delete later, that just calls the getDatabaseConnection() function.

I have done the following:

Ensured the Oracle Driver is in the classpath.  Through Eclipse, Right Click the Project in the Workspace, go to **Properties**, choose **Java Build Path**, click **Libraries** tab, click **Add External JARs**, add file **OJDBC14.jar** to class path.

Placed the OJDBC14.jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

No good.

I also tried to use MySQL.  Did Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") instead and loaded the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" file instead.

And here is my .classpath file, so I'm pretty sure the drivers are there in the class path.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.runtime.runtimeTarget/JBoss 7.1 Runtime">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
 <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Dropbox/Projects/Eintern/Eintern_servlets/intlops/ClientIntakeSystem/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
 <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Dropbox/Projects/Eintern/Eintern_servlets/intlops/ClientIntakeSystem/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I'm just out of ideas here.  I really don't get it because I've written servlets that connected to databases before.  When I did that, I used Tomcat instead of JBoss... that's the only difference I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the deployment assembly and make sure to add external libraries to be exported to the build path.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that exactly.  As I said above, I already added the driver JAR file to the build path through Eclipse through Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries tab.

Comment: I'm just now seeing your response...So that part refers to what is compiled and run when you compile locally on Eclipse, but when you deploy to the server the jar isn't specifically deployed unless you specify under Deployment Assembly. Right-click on Project Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add... > Java Build Path Entries.